# How can I use GREP to decide if every line in a file matches my pattern?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am trying to check if every line in a file matches my pattern (4 characters followed by 4 digits). I tried using GREP with -x -P -v -q options so it returns 1 if my file doesn't match the requirements. I expect it to return nothing in case the file is correct, but it returns nothing even if the file has an error.
$4 is my input file.
My code is:

```
if [ -f $4 ] && [ `grep -q -P -x -v [[a-z]x{4}/[\dx{4}] $4` ]
then
echo "error"
exit 1
fi
```

input example:
bmkj2132
ahgc3478
(no uppercase)

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't check the output of `grep`, check its exit code.

```
if [ -f "$4" ] && grep -q ...
```

Note the double quotes around `$4` - otherwise a file name containing whitespace will break the script.

Also, single quote the regex. Square brackets are special in bash and you don't want the regex to suddenly change (expand) when a random filename exists.

Also note that `x` doesn't mean "times" (under -e, -E, -P neither). The quantifier just follows the quantified with no operator in between:

```
echo abcd1234 | grep -xP '[a-z]{4}\d{4}'
```

So, the full condition should be

```
if [ -f "$4" ] && grep -qvxP '[a-z]{4}\d{4}' "$4" ; then
    echo Error >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Are you sure you want to continue if the file doesn't exist? If not, change the condition to

```
if ! [ -f "$4" ] || grep ...
```

BTW, you don't really need the PCRE expression here. If you replace `\d` by `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`, you can switch to `-E` (extended regular expression).

Comment: very detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The point about using the exit code of `grep` is that it does not match the required condition.

Try the following:

```
if [ -f "$4" ] ; then
    wronglines=$(grep -v pattern "$4")
    if [ "$wronglines" = "" ] ; then
        echo "all is well"
    else
        echo "a wrong line in the file"
    fi
else
    echo "cannot even find the file"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44066484/12109091) answer describes how we can use `grep` to search for any line *not* matching a particular regex pattern. We can modify this to provide a one-liner.

```
grep -Evq "[1-2]" file.txt && echo "error" && exit 1 || true
```

On the following `file.txt`, the error message and exit code will be triggered:

```
1
2
3
```

Without `|| true`, this will always have an false return code. Additionally, this only works for the specified use case; modifying `exit 1` to something like `true` will break the one-liner.

The regex pattern included within this example should be modified to the desired pattern.